# How can I find the percentage of my users whose birth date is between 1980 and 1996. 

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

i'm trying to find the percentage of my users whose birth date is between 1980 and 1996.

I can't find how to do it:

```
SELECT Sum
(WHEN userBirthDate BETWEEN '1980/01/01' AND '1996/12/31'
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / Count(userID) as total
FROM user
```

The error mysql returns is syntax:

```
 ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEN userBirthDate BETWEEN '1980/01/01' AND '1996/12/31' THEN 1 ELSE 0)' at line 1
```

how can i do it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Sum(case WHEN userBirthDate BETWEEN '1980/01/01' AND '1996/12/31'
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
       END) * 100 / Count(userID) as total
FROM `user`
```

or just

```
SELECT Sum(userBirthDate BETWEEN '1980/01/01' AND '1996/12/31') * 100 / Count(userID) as total
FROM `user`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Sum
(IF( userBirthDate BETWEEN '1980/01/01' AND '1996/12/31', 1 , 0 )) * 100 / Count(userID) as total
FROM user
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Sum
(CASE WHEN userBirthDate BETWEEN '1980/01/01' AND '1996/12/31'
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / Count(userID) as total
FROM user
```